# In Spring: Using Interface as RequestBody and returning the right class

Tags: java, spring, interface, controller

I am trying to use an interface in a Spring controller, and having trouble with instantiating the right class.

I have the following method:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/settings/features/{feature}", method=RequestMethod.POST, produces = "application/json; charset=utf-8")
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntityWrapper setFeatureSettings(
        HttpServletRequest request,
        @PathVariable Feature feature,
        @RequestBody IFeatureSettings featureSettings,
        HttpServletResponse response
        ) {
           ...
        }
```

I have several classes which implement IFeatureSettings, and I need to instantiate the correct class for the input.  I can know which is the correct class by looking at feature (it is an enum).  So for feature A I will have AFeatureSettingsImpl and for feature B I will have BFeatureSettingsImpl.

Ideally, there would be some way to step in the middle and say: this time, fill class AFeatureSettingsImpl with data and return it as the interface implementation.

I've been looking at HandlerMethodArgumentResolver and it sounds like the right way to go, but I'm not sure how to do this.  I'll need access to the feature argument, which will hopefully be resolved before I get to my resolution code (or I'll need to resolve it myself).

Answer (score 0):

what about writing another method that takes `feature` and `bodyObject` as parameters?

Something like

```
private final IFeatureSettings getFeatureImpl(Feature feature, Object bodyObject) {
switch(feature) {
case a: return new AFeatureSettingsImpl;
...
   }
}
```

Btw, I really don't know if the thing in the middle you want exists.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but the problem is not with picking the right implementing class, it's about having Spring automatically create the right class from the input.  This is a Spring question.

Answer (score 0):

The simple solution would be to use `Map` instead of `IFeatureSettings` in the method signature. Then based on your `Feature` discriminator you can manually instantiate and populate a bean. Using `Apache BeanUtils` it would look something like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/settings/features/{feature}", method=RequestMethod.POST, produces = "application/json; charset=utf-8")
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntityWrapper setFeatureSettings(
    HttpServletRequest request,
    @PathVariable Feature feature,
    @RequestBody Map featureSettings,
    HttpServletResponse response) {
        IFeatureSettings bean = createBean(feature); // instantiating the right bean based on the feature discriminator
        BeanUtils.populate(bean, featureSettings);
        ...
}
```

In case you want to make it more generic have a look on HttpMessageConverters. Spring is using the [MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/http/converter/json/MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter.html) by default to bind json with `@RequestBody`. You have to extend this converter with your custom logic. Keep in mind that the feature discriminator cannot be an independent argument in this case because you need access to it in your converter. You could put in the HTTP header to make it work. The `readInternal` method of the converter would look something like:

```
@Override
protected Object readInternal(Class<?> clazz, HttpInputMessage inputMessage) throws IOException, HttpMessageNotReadableException {
    Class<?> actualClass = lookupByFeature(inputMessage.getHeaders().get("feature")); // returns the actual Class type based on the feature found in the header
    return super.readInternal(actualClass, inputMessage); // and now the original implementation can use the actual type instead of the interface
}
```

Comment: Adding a map as the parameter would not solve my problem as Spring would not know how to fill it on its own, so there's no reason for having that map as part of the method parameters.  I can of course manually instantiate the classes based on the different features, as you suggested, but I'd rather build a more general purpose solution which will work for other cases as well.  Using message converters is an alternative (albeit not such a good one), it would mean that I would have to manually bind myself again, and would somehow have to access the feature parameter, again, manually.

Comment: That's not right. Spring is able to populate a map with the key-value pairs from your json. If you want a more generic solution you need to go with the converters as described above. You cannot avoid writing the binding logic yourself. How could Spring know about your enum->bean implementation mapping otherwise?

Comment: The problem is that the input for Spring (jackson actually) is an object with no hint regarding the type of the object, and the interface on the server side does not say anything about which implementing class can be used (it's just an interface, the Imp part is unknown).  So how would jackson know which implementing class to choose in order to map the values it got to a real object?

Comment: It's not Jackson but Spring's MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter! This is what you need to extend and override the readInternal method to be able choose the right bean implementation based on the feature discriminator. This is why the discriminator has to go to the HTTP header. I'll update my answer with some more details to make it clear.

Comment: This answer looks like a good direction, I will give it a try, thank you!  I'll update on success/failure.